# Consul Watch : How to run a script on change of a Node Address

Tags: curl, consul

I have the following consul service registered.

```
curl -s -X GET http://<CONSUL_URL>/v1/catalog/service/myservice | jq .
[
  {
    "ServicePort": 0000,
    "ServiceAddress": "",
    "ServiceTags": null,
    "ServiceName": "myservice",
    "ServiceID": "myservice",
    "Address": "10.3.6.28",
    "Node": "myservice-one"
  },
  {
    "ServicePort": 0000,
    "ServiceAddress": "",
    "ServiceTags": null,
    "ServiceName": "myservice",
    "ServiceID": "myservice",
    "Address": "10.3.6.28",
    "Node": "myservice-main"
  },
  {
    "ServicePort": 0000,
    "ServiceAddress": "",
    "ServiceTags": null,
    "ServiceName": "myservice",
    "ServiceID": "myservice",
    "Address": "10.3.6.26",
    "Node": "myservice-two"
  },
  {
    "ServicePort": 0000,
    "ServiceAddress": "",
    "ServiceTags": null,
    "ServiceName": "myservice",
    "ServiceID": "myservice",
    "Address": "10.3.6.27",
    "Node": "myservice-three"
  }
]


 curl -s -X GET http://10.3.6.21:8500/v1/catalog/node/myservice-main | jq .
{
  "Services": {
    "myservice": {
      "Port": 0000,
      "Address": "",
      "Tags": null,
      "Service": "myservice",
      "ID": "myservice"
    }
  },
  "Node": {
    "Address": "10.3.6.28",
    "Node": "myservice-main"
  }
}
```

As shown here, I have a Node myservice-main within the myservice service that I have. I want to execute some specific stuff when the address of myservice-main changes. I read that consul watch can be helpful to achieve it but I am not able to write the curl command for the same. Could anyone point me to the http api which I can use to achieve my requirement? I can only use HTTP apis(curl) and shell script as I want ot do it from a remote system

Answer (score 0):

To do blocking queries you would need to look at the `X-Consul-Index` header in the response and use it as a query parameter in the URL for your next query. [Here is the documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http.html).

But the documentation also states that your call might return even if there was no change in the service. And you have to take care of the index numbers.

I suggest you have a look at [consul template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) instead: You would write a template file with all the information you want to monitor, including the IP adresses. consul template will then call your script as soon as any of this information changes.